# listen for Preference button click in Main Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, preferences

Im using a settings activity with a preference.xml to create a settings menu. Im trying to listen to a button click from my settings activity in my main activity. I cant seem to figure out how to accomplish this?

Comment: "Im trying to listen to a button click from my settings activity in my main activity." - don't do this. There is no reason one Activity should be aware of what is happening in another. If you need to make updates to the MainActivity AFTER you return from the settings, use onActivityResult or reload the settings in onStart()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do that by listening to changes in `SharedPreferences` with [SharedPreferences#registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences#registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener)).

Comment: Could I also use onPreferenceClickListener? That is what I have been trying to use with no success. Thanks.

Comment: You'd need to keep a reference of one `Activity` in another `Activity`, which can be done, but it's not recommended. With that you'd be risking with having memory leaks and go against good programming principles. Registering the `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` is way better and safer solution.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I will give OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener a try. Thanks